# Xampp Portable 7.3.1 how to install composer

Tags: php

I have started using Xampp 7.3.1. PORTABLE

it is unpacked in d:\xampp

I'm trying to install Composer but I have this issue not seen in another question similar to this,

maybe because something changed in php.ini

what I see in the log, kindly see the screenshot, is that the missing modules ( *impossibile trovare il modulo specificato* )

don't show the D:\ path letter

[image]

can you kindly hint what is going wrong?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Ok

sorry to answer by myself , I have found this in the php.ini

```
extension_dir = "\xampp\php\ext"
```

I have changed it to

```
extension_dir = "D:\xampp\php\ext"
```

[image]

and left untouched all the rest